# python lxml: copy values from one xml file to another where elements match

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have 2 xml files: one with sample data (containing all the elements I need) and another with real data (but doesn't have all the elements). I would like to copy the real values from the second file across to my first file where the element name matches.

I was thinking about achieving this using the iterator somehow

FILE 1

```
  <VKORG>str1234</VKORG>
  <VTWEG>str1234</VTWEG>
  <SPART>str1234</SPART>
  <KUNNR>str1234</KUNNR>
  <KDGRP>str1234</KDGRP>
  <PLTYP>str1234</PLTYP>
  <KONDA>str1234</KONDA>
  <KONDM>str1234</KONDM>
  <WAERK>str1234</WAERK>
  <MATNR>str1234</MATNR>
```

FILE 2

```
  <VKORG>CH12</VKORG>
  <VTWEG>02</VTWEG>
  <MATNR>000000000010000831</MATNR>
```

In this example the 3 fields in file 2 would come across and the remaining fields in File 1 would remain as is (because there is no matching element in File 2).

The actual files are not flat and have multiple levels of nested elements and possibly multiple root elements.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it by creating an index of the file with the real values.

Then iterating through the file you want to populate into, looking things up in your index. Something like:

```
src = lxml.etree.parse('real.xml')
ix = dict()
for n in src.getroot().iterdescendants():
    ix[n.tag] = n

dest = lxml.etree.parse('template.xml')
for n in dest.getroot().iterdescendants():
    if n.tag in ix:
        n.text = ix[n.tag].text
```

You say it's more complex though in terms of the files though - so it's hard for me to say exactly.

Edit: I haven't tested the code above

Comment: @Aidan Kane : I have similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45833925/python-to-merge-certain-xml-tags-from-file1-to-file-2/45852051#45852051  

I am struggling on this from last  2 working day on this. I tried your code, looks like i am missing something but not able to figure.. because XML1 (File1) is not getting updated in my case.  any help will be appreciated.